# Laravel Middleware Auth Group is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Good Day. I had a problem with my authentication which I always redirected back into the login page. I found out that when I add in routes/web.php with this code below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

}
```

the page is always redirected back to the login page. But when I remove that code above, I can proceed to the home page. I trying to wonder how to solve this. I use route group in my past projects and I don't have any problems with that.

UPDATE: I used php artisan test and remodify my ExampleTest.php codes.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\User;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function testApplication()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                         ->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
                         ->get('/');
    }
}
```

These are the results

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\nuadu_helpdesk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:273
    269|      */
    270|     protected function getRawAttributes(array $attributes = [])
    271|     {
    272|         if (! isset($this->definitions[$this->class])) {
  > 273|             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unable to locate factory for [{$this->class}].");
    274|         }
    275|
    276|         $definition = call_user_func(
    277|             $this->definitions[$this->class],

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\nuadu_helpdesk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder.php:296
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::getRawAttributes([])

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\nuadu_helpdesk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes.php:155
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
```

Comment: May be you have a session issue your session is unset after page refresh/ redirect

Comment: that is what the `auth` middleware does, it will redirect you to the `login` if you are not authenticated

Comment: How to fix those session issues? I had still no idea about those.

Comment: But I'm logging in with the account, both username, and password. Instead of authenticated, I redirect back to the login page.

Comment: you are facing this issue in you local or after upload?

Comment: is this route group in your `web.php` routes file?

Comment: In my local using xampp @ÃbdùlMøïz

Comment: yes in web.php routes file @lagbox

Comment: well if you are certain you logged in, then as said by ÃbdùlMøïz it is probably a session issue (cookie issue) ... try clearing your cookies for this site and try to login again ... though this doesnt quite sound right because to be able to login with a form with a csrf token you would need sessions to be working

Comment: where can I manipulate those sessions?

Comment: delete vendor folder and composer.lock file and again run composer install

Comment: still the same @AbdulMoiz

Comment: I update my question. I test the sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about my problem. I checked using the auth and dd. I used a different primary key with user_id and it is a string type. I forgot to declare it in my user.php

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

By default, the primary key will always be the id. If you declare a different column name that will serve as your primary key, don't forget to declare the codes that I stated above, or else you end not reading the auth or not logging in.

Answer (score 0):

inside routes.php file you not write where to redirect. so please add like below..

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
  return redirect('/');  //by default you can change it as your requirments.
}
```